# Drupal 7: Checkbox label with links in it

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

is it possible to add a simple html link in the label/title of a checkbox? I tried the following code:

```
<?php
$form['legal']['#type'] = 'checkbox';
$form['legal']['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['legal']['#title'] = t(
  'You must accept our @tos and @legals',
  array(
    '@tos'    => l(t('terms of service'), 'node/6'),
    '@legals' => l(t('legals'), 'node/7')
  )
);
?>
```

But that produces the follwing label (the html markup isn't "translated"):

"You must accept our < a href="/node/6">terms of service< /a> and < a href="/node/7">legals< /a> *"

(I've added spaces after the opening brackets so that it will not be converted to the link i want to have)

Is it not possible to do such things? I Am new to drupal. Perhaps somebody can help me... Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens before you force the text to be printed as plain text.

```
<?php
$form['legal']['#type'] = 'checkbox';
$form['legal']['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['legal']['#title'] = t(
  'You must accept our !tos and !legals',
  array(
    '!tos'    => l(t('terms of service'), 'node/6'),
    '!legals' => l(t('legals'), 'node/7')
  )
);
?>
```

Note that you are using [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function, which acts differently on replacement's prefix. 
If you put `@tos`, it will be run through check_plain() so HTML will never be processed by the browser as it encodes HTML entities.

`!tos` allows HTML markup as it will not be `check_plain()`'d.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer! I searched for something like this all the time, but was not lucky. I should have read the documentation about the t() function more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can try to use `#prefix`.

```
$form['legal']['#prefix'] = t(
  'You must accept our @tos and @legals',
  array(
    '@tos'    => l(t('terms of service'), 'node/6'),
    '@legals' => l(t('legals'), 'node/7')
  )
);
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: This does not help. But I'm confused that this still does not print HTML although the Form API Reference says that...

Comment: -1. This is entirely wrong. FAPI allows HTML markup but @tos forces text to be check_plain().

Comment: Big thx Ayesh. That helped me out! Without the placeholders, everything works just fine.

Comment: @Muhammad no offense I just needed to point that with a downvote. Hope it's fine :)